# Access of Variables in Multiple Xaml files

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

How can we access variable from one Xaml file in to another xaml file in a same project

Comment: The more detail you put in your question about your actual goals the more help we can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml files don't have variables.  Do you mean variables in the code-behind of the Xaml file in a Silverlight Application?

If the so the answer is yes you simply expose a variable as a property:-

```
public string MyVariable { get; private set; }
```

In the above example external code can read MyVariable but can't write to it.

Having said that I'm gonna guess that is not what you are after but thats the problem when you only use a single sentence in your question.  ;)